# SQL Modify_date resolution in milliseconds

Tags: sql-server

I noticed that the Modify_date on 275 object in my database always had a final milliseconds digit of either 0, 3 or 7. This looks like 0/3, 1/3 (rounded down) and 2/3 (rounded up).

I wrote this query to check my entire database and it is true:

```sql
with a as (
select name,type_desc,modify_date, 
convert(int,DATEPART(MS,modify_date)) Mils
from sys.objects
),
 
b as (
select *,
RIGHT(Mils,1) rm
from a)
 
select * from b
order by rm
```

I won't list all 275 rows, but they are all 0, 3 or 7.

I'm intrigued to understand what might cause this time to be no more than 3 milliseconds accurate?

Comment: This is a known precision item in datetime.  you can always go to datetime2 to define and increase the precision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datetime` is accurate to 1/300th of a second. This is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#DateandTimeDataTypes) as well.

As the 1/300th are rounded, then `0.0000000` will show as `0.000`, `0.003333333333` as `0.003` and finally `0.00666666666666` and `0.007`.

If you want a higher precision (say to 1/1000th of a second), then you would need to use the newer `datetime2` data type and give it a precision of `3` (`datetime2(3)`). Any existing values will retain the existing values though.

If you do go for even greater accuracy (say `datetime2(7)`), and change your existing column to this data type, then depending on what version you are using you will get different results. In newer versions, the `datetime` value `2020-09-24T17:14:01.003` would be converted to `2020-09-24T17:14:01.0033333` however in older versions `2020-09-24T17:14:01.0030000`. This is something you should bare in mind.

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you correctly, you want to get the last decimal digit from the millisecond component of your `datetime`.

If so, you can use `datepart()` and arithmethics as follows:

```
datepart(ms, modify_date) - datepart(ms, modify_date) / 10 * 10
```

Here is a [simplified demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=13ac9e5a35567030241f8c3c2de23d4a):

```sql
declare @modify_date datetime2 = getdate();
select @modify_date original, 
    datepart(ms, @modify_date) ms, 
    datepart(ms, @modify_date) - datepart(ms, @modify_date) / 10 * 10 result

original                    |  ms | result
:-------------------------- | --: | -----:
2020-09-24 17:11:36.3733333 | 373 |      3
```

Comment: Thank you. I was going to use something like this but then decided to do it as a string. Halfway through had this abortive "chimera" code, but it seemed to work so I kept it!